# Round to nearest of specified numbers in Python?

Tags: python, integer, rounding

Is it possible to round a number to the nearest of a few pre defined numbers?

It would probably look something like
`round(x,3,6,13)`, where it rounds x to the nearest of the specified numbers.

So you would get:

`x = 4`        `round(x,3,6,13) = 3`

`x = 7`        `round(x,3,6,13) = 6`

`x = 10`        `round(x,3,6,13) = 13`

Comment: It is definitely possible. What have you tried?

Comment: you probably want the second argument to be at least a list

Comment: If this was numpy, you would use `np.searchsorted`.

Comment: `np.searchsorted` is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Wow, really? [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) works more like floor or ceiling rather than rounding. I mean, after using it, you still need to add your own logic to determine which of the two bounding elements is closer. (Granted, that may still be better than some of the answers in the question which this is a duplicate of.)